# Get value from an IBOutlet from another class

Tags: ios, swift, class

I'm trying to make a call to my database where the city of my user will be equal to the location found thanks to Core Location. I can successfully make a call to the database and find the geolocation, I can also make a query where city = "nameOfACity" but I don't figure out how to call data where city = cityFromCoreLocation.

I can't call the variable I created for the result of the Geolocation as it's located in another class and displayed as an IBOutlet. I was wondering if I may :
- find a way to call that IBOutlet
- or call directly the placemark.locality from Geocoder function? (which I can't do for the moment as it is also in another class.

I'm new to swift so I still don't know how to call a variable from a different class... I read topics on this subject but they don't adapt to the current case.

Here is my code :

Call to the data base :

```
import UIKit

let sharedInstance = ModelBD()

class ModelBD: NSObject {

var database: FMDatabase? = nil

class func getInstance() -> ModelBD {
    if (sharedInstance.database == nil) {
        sharedInstance.database = FMDatabase(path: Utilities.getPath("bddFrance.sqlite"))
    }

    return sharedInstance
}


func getAllArticles() -> NSMutableArray {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()

    let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM bddF WHERE ville = \(VC0.myCity)", withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    let arrDataArticles : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    if (resultSet != nil) {
        while resultSet.next() {
            let articlesInfo : ArticlesData = ArticlesData()
            articlesInfo.nameArticle = resultSet.stringForColumn("nom")
            articlesInfo.cityArticle = resultSet.stringForColumn("ville")
            articlesInfo.districtArticle = resultSet.stringForColumn("quartier")
            articlesInfo.countryArticle = resultSet.stringForColumn("pays")

            print("--")
            print("nameArticle \(articlesInfo.nameArticle)")
            print("cityArticle \(articlesInfo.cityArticle)")
            print("districtArticle \(articlesInfo.districtArticle)")
            print("countryArticle \(articlesInfo.countryArticle)")

            arrDataArticles.addObject(articlesInfo)
        }
    }

    sharedInstance.database!.close()
    return arrDataArticles
}
}
```

Class where is located the variable that I need :

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class VC0: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let LocationManager = CLLocationManager()

var arrDataArticles: NSMutableArray!

@IBOutlet weak var myCity: UINavigationItem!

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var images = UIImage(named: "avatar")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //CoreLocation
    self.LocationManager.delegate = self
    self.LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Data
    self.getAllArticles()
}

//Location
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print("Error")
        }

        if let pm = placemarks?.first {
            self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
        }
        else {
            print("Error : data error")
        }

    })
}

func displayLocationInfo (placemark: CLPlacemark) {

    self.LocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    print(placemark.subThoroughfare)
    print(placemark.thoroughfare)
    print(placemark.locality)
    print(placemark.postalCode)
    print(placemark.subAdministrativeArea)
    print(placemark.administrativeArea)
    print(placemark.country)
    myCity.title = placemark.locality

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error :" + error.localizedDescription)
}

//Data
func getAllArticles() {
    arrDataArticles = NSMutableArray()
    arrDataArticles = ModelBD.getInstance().getAllArticles()
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrDataArticles.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell

    let article: ArticlesData = arrDataArticles.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! ArticlesData

    myCell.rank.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    myCell.photo.image = images
    myCell.name.text = article.nameArticle
    myCell.city.text = article.districtArticle

    return myCell
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `getAllArticles` method in `ModelBD` class to accept city (String) as an argument.

```
func getAllArticlesFromCity(city: String) -> NSMutableArray {
    sharedInstance.database!.open()

    let resultSet: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM bddF WHERE ville = '\(city)'", withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    ...
```

Then in your `VC0`, you can just pass the city in that method:

```
func getAllArticles() {
    if let city = myCity.title {
      arrDataArticles = NSMutableArray()
      arrDataArticles = ModelBD.getInstance().getAllArticlesFromCity(city)
      myTableView.reloadData()
    } 
}
```

And you should only call `self.getAllArticles` after you get the location. Don't call it on `viewDidLoad`.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
  //...
  if let pm = placemarks?.first {
    self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
    self.getAllArticles()
  }
  //...
```

Comment: It displays an "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error when I build it.

Comment: which line does the crash happen?

Comment: I guess you should not call `self.getAllArticles()` on `viewDidLoad` because at that time, you still haven't got the user location yet. Please make the call only after you have the location. (for example: call after `self.displayLocationInfo(pm)` in `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`. But make sure to call it once because the location is constantly updated.

Comment: It crashes on that line : arrDataArticles = ModelBD.getInstance().getAllArticlesFromCity(myCity.title)

Comment: It forced me to add a "!" as an optional after "title"

Comment: Did you remove the call `self.getAllArticles()` in `viewDidLoad` yet? And I did update my answer to safely unwrap the `city` variable before using it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't have time to do it, I tried with your instruction and now the same error message appears on another line in my viewController. On this line : func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrDataArticles.count //it appears here

Comment: That's because you haven't initialized the `arrDataArticles` yet. Add this to your `viewDidLoad` method: `arrDataArticles = NSMutableArray()`

Comment: Ok, it's not crashing anymore but it's not displaying any value from the database...

Comment: May it be because the label is empty and it displays the location but when we say ville = \(city) it doesn't take the location into consideration?

Comment: yes, it should. Because we fetch the articles only after we got the user location. Please make sure that the method `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])` get called (put a breakpoint inside it). And the `self.getAllArticles()` method also get called after that.

Comment: should be like this `ville = \(city)`. Not this `ville = (city)`.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake in my comment but it was written like this

Comment: the func locationManager gets called, how can I check that self.getAllArticles() also gets called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120310/discussion-between-hoang-tran-and-theo-fleismaher).